# Stripping html tags out of a title using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript function currently overriding a html display to allow longer titles to display over the programs replacement string rule which does work.  The problem I am seeing though is even though it does work, the html tags are showing up in the title:

So in a folder structure it shows like this (which is correct):  Aggregated Pricing Item Test - **foo**

but in the detail page title it is showing up like this after the script executes:

```
 Aggregated Pricing Item Test - <b>foo</b>
```

Is there anyway to change the existing javascript to either use or eliminate it displaying the html elements?

Here is the code we are using for the override:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jSINI.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var doc_id = CallSINIMethod("GetValue",["SystemProperty","CurrentUserDocument", null]);
    var int_id = CallSINIMethod("GetValue",["DocumentProperty","ProductID", doc_id]);
    var prod_name = CallSINIMethod("GetValue",["ProductProperty","DisplayName", int_id]);
    $('div.areaTitle').text(prod_name);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using the `text` property, it will display exactly what you give it, you need to change that to `html` so it will display correctly.

```
$('div.areaTitle').html(prod_name);
```

Comment: Yep that did it.   Thank you very much